# Why does TYPO3 remove values of style="" attributes during SVG rendering?

Tags: svg, typo3, html-rendering, typo3-10.x

On my TYPO3 v10 website I have some SVG icons in use, no problem.

I also have a few more complex SVG Figures (created with Inkscape), that I want to include in TYPO3 website. Of course I can upload the .svg files to the `fileadmin/` folder, and link to them with the Text+Image (or Text+Media) Content Elements.

In the Backend, TYPO3 generates some fine png-thumbnails for preview.  So far so good.

The file can be downloaded directly, from its `fileadmin/images` ... location.

However, inside web pages, my SVGs are not displayed as they should.

A lot of styling information gets removed from the SVG and I don't know where.

Here is a screenshot of the original vs corrupted image (as displayed in the TYPO3 frontend).

[image]

Here is a graphical diff that shows the difference between the figures.

[image]

It turns out that at some time during the rendering process, TYPO3 removes the values from the `style="...."` SVG attributes. See reddish boxes.

All my more complex SVGs look like the one on the right when embedded in TYPO3.

Here is the SVG if you want to try yourself: [image](https://svgshare.com/s/_gw) on [SVGshare.com](https://svgshare.com/i/_gw.svg)

On the right, many `style` attributes have been set to `style=""`.

but why?

Comment: Do you use the latest version of TYPO3 v10? Your SVGshare link is broken. Can you upload the SVG somewhere else, e.g. Pastebin?

Comment: The SVGshare link works for me. I've just entered `curl -sL https://svgshare.com/i/_gw.svg` (on some remote host I am ssh'd in as a new user) and then I see the XML on the screen. -  I use typo3   10.4.15.

Comment: Now I've upgraded to the current release, v10.4.20. Same thing, SVG error is still there.

Answer (score 1):

[TYPO3 9 introduced an *SVG Sanitizer*](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Important-94492-IntroduceSVGSanitizer.html), which automatically modifies SVG files during "fileadmin upload time", meaning it removes any `<style ...>` elements from the uploaded SVG file.

In TYPO3 10 and later versions, this SVG Sanitizer is by default automatically set up via Symfony dependency injection via [`core`'s `Services.yaml`](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/v10.4.31/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/Services.yaml#L345).

You can remove the SVG Sanitizer via your own site extension's `Services.yaml`, e.g. for your `myextension/Configuration/Services.yaml`:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  # ...

  # remove TYPO3's default-autowired SvgSanitizer, which tampers with filadmin uploaded SVGs (e.g. removes necessary <style> information)'
  TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Security\SvgEventListener: ~
```

The tilde (`~`) removes/overwrites the definition previously set up by `core`'s `Services.yaml` ( https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html ).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem of your individual TYPO3 installation. I've just tested your SVG image in a brand new TYPO3 v10 installation and the image is rendered properly in backend and frontend.

Maybe you have some 3rd party extensions installed who postprocess the HTML output of TYPO3, e.g EXT:sourceopt or EXT:scriptmerger.

Comment: On my Firefox, the SVG gets displayed correctly *once*. Have you right-clicked, opened the SVG image in a new tab, and hit "reload"? -- It seems to be a longstanding Firefox Issue.  Inkscape saved my SVG with *inline CSS-styles*, and Firefox removes these, by default. Because they  are a security loophole, closed with a CSP . I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

It's Firefox, not TYPO3, who removes the `style="..."`  attribute values. This seems to be a longstanding Firefox Issue, solved.

See [Bugzilla Issue 1262842](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1262842): *[CSP] Blocks the use of style attributes inside SVG without generating console errors*.

Look for "triply confusing" in the [first comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1262842#c0).

Inline CSS styles can be a security Problem, and therefore Firefox has a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) in place, in order to correct this.

An explainer for the mitigation strategies, written jointly by professional Security Engineers is given in this [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_nYS4gWYO2Oh8rYDyPglXIKNsgCRVhmjHqWlTAHst7c/edit#heading=h.ue3d7ohicxh3) and in [Gihub Repo](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp) (*Content Security Policy*), [Issue 45](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/45), *Further granularity of unsafe-inline styles*.

> Script inline attributes are a difficult subject to approach when it
> comes to CSP,  they have the same amount of power as any other script
> element but they don’t have ways to be whitelisted, for example, by a
> nonce or hash. This means that the actual content of the attribute is
> mostly the only deciding factor.

I don't understand everything mentioned in these docs and discussions. Inline-`style` Elements seem to be vulnerable to XSS attacks, and then attacker can put CSS `url()` in there for instance.

#### Quick-and-dirty solution

Use Inkscape and save as "optimized SVG", and check the option "Convert CSS Attributes to XML attributes". See attached screenshot of the Inkscape Dialog (Linux).

[image: inkscape dialog]

This solution was [proposed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1262842#c4) by a web-developer from the GIMP  devteam.